# Jquery Plugin for Image upload on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want an jquery inline editor that can be placed at more than one place and onclick one should be able to convert image to an image uploaded
for eg if there is an image , and user clicks on the image it should show user an image uploader
I did this with simple javascript but problem i am facing is it is not that stable like if i upload image twice and other stuffs.
Do someone knows of plugin that does this. It should be ajax based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Jeditable plugein to Jquery Framework

Here you can find the life example of file upload: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/custom.html

Comment: But it doesnt make image editable... I want to be able to click on images and change them into uploader.
the one you showed is for text, Badly struck at this problem

Comment: Follow my link and look better, there is Ajax File Upload examples there. Click on "edit me!" text and the magic will heppen :)

Comment: You are welcome! The inline edit action depent to click on item with some class or id. Just add the id to your img (and change the binding at jeditable function) and inline form will showw an img click

Comment: can it also display rich text editor? i mean on click of text depict rich text editor instead of normal edit

Comment: yes, you can do it. also with jedibable. http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/9/wysiwyg-for-jeditable

Comment: Not able to make it i just want bold,italic underline...I followed step by step instructions as there is no downloads...Can you help AGAIN :) ?? please
[here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rigids/5xmxm/)

Comment: No problem, how to send it to you?

Comment: mail me @ rigids.php@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately ajaxupload.js and jeditable.ajaxupload.js does not work with jquery 1.5+ since ajaxupload is using an internal jquery function (jQuery.handleError) which is not part of jquery any more (don't use internal and undocumented functions :-).